# vim execute not working in script

Tags: vimscript, execute

I am using a plugin that expands the word template by a template but only if the word template is followed by a tab. I am trying to write the word new then in insert mode jump to the end of the line then insert the tab, I am on mac too. When I try this command from command mode in vim, it works but when I try it in a vim script it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
let longstring = substitute('template','','\r','i')
call writefile(['template'], l:new, '')
```

```
augroup templates
execute "split"
execute ":normal! A^I;"
execute ":e!" . l:new
augroup END
```

EDIT:
This is the command that works:
> execute ":normal! A^I;"
I am using the UltiSnips, the word needs to be followed by the tab character to kick off the template.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Sorry, but it's really hard to understand what you're doing here, and also hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. The snippet you pasted is using an `augroup` but all that does is group `autocmd`s together and you have none of them. You're using this `l:new` variable that you didn't definite anywhere... It's hard to understand the task itself... You talk about this plug-in that expands the word template, is it the word "template" itself? Which plug-in is the one you're using?

Comment: Which is the command that works when you try it from command mode? What does it do when it works? What happens when it doesn't work? Please [edit] your question and add a lot more details here, otherwise it'll be hard to figure out how to help you here...

Comment: I have edited to answer your questions

Comment: Try using \<tab> instead of ^I.

Comment: \<tab> doesn't work either

Comment: I took out the ; and used the \<tab> now it works as suspected